# Custom actions in Material UI select MenuItem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI Select: https://material-ui.com/components/selects/

The select needs a bit of custom functionality. I have added this in a CodePen sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-3nzpv

- Some MenuItem might need to show a delete icon.
- Selecting an option that has the delete icon (but not clicking the delete icon itself) should not show the delete icon after selection as the selected value. The delete icon should still be a part of the MenuItem though.
  [image]
- Clicking on the delete icon should not select the option but trigger the onClick of the delete icon instead. In essence, the default functionality of MenuItem should not trigger, just the icon onClick.

What's the best way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `renderValue` prop from your `Select` component, in order cu custom render your selected value.

Add the following line to your `Select` component

```js
renderValue={value => currencies.find(el => el.value === value).label}
```

You can check an updated version of your working sandbox [HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-pv9zl)

Also you can check more on `Select` props [HERE](https://material-ui.com/api/select/)

> LE: Update for point 3

In your `<DeleteIcon>` handler `onClick`, you need to stop the propagation of the event further. In the `handleDelete()` function add the `event` parameter and use `e.stopPropagation()` method.

```js
const handleDelete = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log("Delete");
};
```

And your component should look like this

```js
<MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
    <div>{option.label}</div>
    <div>{option.action && <DeleteIcon onClick={handleDelete}/>}/div>
</MenuItem>
/>
```

I've also updated a sandbox, with the last version [HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-pv9zl)

Comment: Thanks @sabbin. Now I have point 1 and 2 working. Any idea how to solve point 3?

Comment: @EricPPereira I've updated my answer with the solution for point 3

Comment: Awesome @sabbin. That seemed to work! I'll check how I can use these solutions on my  application.

Comment: Sorry @sabbin. The onMouseDown solution doesn't work. For some reason this works only when there is an alert.

Comment: @EricPPereira I cannot second guess code, and if it works for alert it works for anything else... Trace your code after that. If you need help post the actual code so I can fully understand your issue

Comment: Also it would be wise to accept the solution as I answered all your points in the question... based on the question and the sandbox, the solution is working.

Comment: Thank you @sabbin. I did accept the answer. Not sure why it didn't reflect but I accepted it again. I updated the CodePen sandbox to demonstrate the issue in point 3. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @EricPPereira I've updated the answer again, also the sandbox

Comment: Thanks @Sabbin. I thought of using `e.stopPropagation();` but I guess I was using it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

On your handleChange method, write a condition to change the value only if the value of a menu item does not have the value that does not need to be selected